# Unable to parse a word in nasm

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, nasm

I got a function description: accepts a buffer address and size as arguments. Reads next word from stdin (skipping whitespaces into buffer). Stops and returns 0 if word is too big for the
buffer specified; otherwise returns a buffer address. This function should null-terminate the accepted string. But the code which I wrote doesn't work when I try to input something like `echo -n "" | ./read_word` or `echo -n "\t   " | ./read_word`. The output is

```
[3]    40467 done                              echo -n "\t   " | 
       40468 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./read_word
```

What can be wrong in my code?

Here it is:

```
read_word:
    xor r8, r8
    xor r9, r9
    mov r9, rdi
    push rdi
    push rsi
    .whitespace_reader:
        call read_char
        
        mov rdi, rax
        push rax
        call .whitespace_checker
        cmp rax, 2
        jz .fail
        
        cmp rax, 0
        pop rax

        jz .whitespace_reader
    
    pop rsi
    pop rdi
         
    .word_reader:
        inc r8
        cmp r8, rsi
        jnb .fail              ; если >=, фейлим, иначе пишем в буфер
        mov byte [rdi], al
        inc rdi

        push rdi
        push rsi
        
        call read_char

        pop rsi
        pop rdi
        push rdi
        mov rdi, rax
        
        push rax
        call .whitespace_checker
        cmp rax, 0
        pop rax
        pop rdi
        jz .success

        jmp .word_reader


    ; возвращает 0, если символ пробельный, 1 если непробельный и 2, если нуль-терминатор
    .whitespace_checker:
        mov rax, rdi
        cmp rax, 0x20
        jz .ret_0
        cmp rax, 0x9
        jz .ret_0
        cmp rax, 0xA
        jz .ret_0
        cmp rax, 0
        jz .ret_2
        
        mov rax, 1
        ret 

        .ret_0:
            mov rax, 0
            ret

        .ret_2:
            mov rax, 2
            ret
    
    .fail:
        xor rax, rax
        ret
        
    .success:
        inc rdi
        mov byte [rdi], 0
        mov rax, r9
        mov rdx, r8
        ret`
```

Comment: Hmmm, probably wrong `push...pop` operations. Before `call .whitespace_checker`, `rax` is on the stack. If `rax=2`, program jumps to `.fail` and there is `ret` instruction. `pop rax` should be after `jz .whitespace_reader`, `jz` should be applied to `cmp rax,0` And same with `jz .success` there is `ret`, pop whatever is on the stack.

Comment: @Nassau so the code should be like this: 'read_word:
    xor r8, r8
    xor r9, r9
    mov r9, rdi
    push rdi
    push rsi
    .whitespace_reader:
        call read_char
        
        mov rdi, rax
        push rdi
        call .whitespace_checker
        cmp rax, 2
        pop rdi
        jz .fail
        
        cmp rax, 0
        mov rax, rdi

        jz .whitespace_reader
    
    pop rsi
    pop rdi'?

Comment: If You `push` value on the stack You should `pop` it. If You use `call` You should use `ret` at the end of the procedure. What if after `call .whitespace_checker`, `rax = 2`? Program will jump to `.fail` and there is `ret` instruction which pop returning adress from the stack but on the stack there is no address, there is `rsi`. In other cases, `rax = 0 or 1`,hmmm, should be ok, I think.  So maybe that's why this error `segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I don't know what to add more, maybe someone else will see something I can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your examples just contain whitespace plus a terminating zero. The  *.whitespace_reader* will loop through the whitespace and then stumble upon the terminating zero for which it will jump to *.fail*. The `ret` instruction there will be using an unbalanced stack as the return address is blocked by the presence of the RDI, RSI, and RAX registers that you have pushed. There's no quick fix for this in your present code as it contains additional problems.

- Since it's `r12`, `r13`, `r14`, `r15`, `rbx`, `rsp`, and `rbp` that are the call-preserved registers, there's no guarantee that your R8 and R9 registers will survive the call to *read_char*.
- When calling the *.whitespace_checker*, you are complicating matters trying to follow the calling convention to store the first argument in RDI. This *.whitespace_checker* is your own subroutine and is used locally anyway, so it's totally fine to just invoke it with the argument already in RAX. And it is also fine to return the result in any register that you find convenient, like RDX in this case.
- Since the *.whitespace_checker* returns a tri-state result {0,1,2}, you only need a single `cmp dl, 1` instruction to cover all possible outcomes.
- The `inc rdi` in *.success* would leave an unused byte in the buffer and potentially place the new terminating-zero outside of the buffer!

This is my rewrite, incorporating all of the above:

```
; IN (rdi,rsi) OUT (rax,rdx)
read_word:
    push rbx                  ; Save call-preserved registers
    push r12
    push r13
    xor  ebx, ebx             ; WordLength = 0
    mov  r12, rdi             ; BufferAddress
    mov  r13, rsi             ; BufferSize

.whitespace_reader:           ; Skip leading whitespace
    call read_char            ; -> RAX
    call .whitespace_checker  ; -> RDX={0,1,2}
    cmp  dl, 1
    jb   .whitespace_reader   ; 0 == Whitespace
    ja   .fail                ; 2 == Terminating zero
                              ; 1 == Normal character
.word_reader:
    inc  rbx
    cmp  rbx, r13
    jnb  .fail 
    mov  [r12], al
    inc  r12
    call read_char            ; -> RAX
    call .whitespace_checker  ; -> RDX={0,1,2}
    cmp  dl, 1
    je   .word_reader         ; 1 == Normal character
.success:
    mov  byte [r12], 0        ; New terminating-zero
    mov  rax, r12             ; WordAddress to RAX
    sub  rax, rbx
    mov  rdx, rbx             ; WordLength to RDX
    jmp  .done

; IN (rax) OUT (rdx)
.whitespace_checker:
    xor  edx, edx             ; 0 == Whitespace
    cmp  al, 32
    je   .ret
    cmp  al, 9
    je   .ret
    cmp  al, 10
    je   .ret
    inc  edx                  ; 1 == Normal character
    test al, al
    jnz  .ret
    inc  edx                  ; 2 == Terminating zero
.ret:
    ret
    
.fail:
    xor  eax, eax
.done:
    pop  r13                  ; Restore call-preserved registers
    pop  r12
    pop  rbx
    ret
```

Comment: Please, change dh to dl in .success. Perfect! Thank you very much!